# Can we calculate the gravitation radiation using the similar method in electrodynamics?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

Let's just forget GR for the moment. Newton's theory of gravity and Maxwell's theory of electrodynamics are very similar,i.e both Columb type interaction, can we just use the method develop there to calculate the radiation of earth moving around sun? First, we can define the energy density of field as $$\rho=-\frac{1}{8\pi G_N} g^2$$
Then we can use all the technique developed in EM to calculate the radiation.

Comment: You can't forget GR because GR is the only theory of gravitation (at the moment) that includes gravitational radiation (and Newton is actually 100% wrong conceptually, even though he gave us the correct result in the low field "DC" case). What you can do is to linearize general relativity (on a flat background) and the linearized field equations can be handled much easier than the full ones. This is usually discussed in textbooks on GR quite extensively. Did you look it up, e.g. in Weinberg's textbook?